# Debugging core file for image built without gdb flag -g

Tags: c, gdb

Consider a field case, where we won't provide the image built with gdb flags.
Now is there any link or documentation or any such similar stuffs which helps in
debugging the core file generated in the field.(Remember the image is not built with -g gdb flag).

Some pointers would be really useful !!

Comment: As far as I know, you must have symbols enabled in the binary file in order to debug the core file.  Remember that the core file is just the memory layout of the application at point of execution X.  You must include the application since this is how gdb can tell what frames were on the stack and what symbols those lines map to.

Answer (score 3):

An even better solution is to always build your program with -g (which at least for GCC does not inhibit optimization). Then you can use objcopy to create [separate debug files](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) which you do not ship with the product, and stripped binaries which you do ship.

Then when you load a core from the field on a development machine, where the debug symbols are present, GDB will load the debug symbols from the separate files. In the field, the debug symbol files are not present, since you didn't ship them, so the debug info is not available.

If applicable, you can also create a DVD or USB key with the symbol files so that a technician can bring symbols with them to analyze a core file on-site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your executable with `-g` (you may also specify `-O`). You then ship a stripped version of the executable (`man strip`). Any core file will be compatible with either version.

Comment: And if the original image wasn't built with -g, you can usually rebuild the image (minding everything from code to the compilersystem header files etc. )remains the same) with -g, and analyze a core file from the image built without -g using the image built with -g